# Does LLVM do simple arithmetic before compiling?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, llvm

I often see in code things like `60*60` instead of `3600`. Do they both compiler to the same exact thing? I.e., does the precompiler replace 60*60 with `3600` for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, constant expressions are evaluated at compile-time.

Answer (score 7):

To be perfectly correct, it is not required, but most compilers do it.
Read about [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Comment: The question was about a particular implementation, though.

Comment: +1 for the link and the corresponding phrase used in compiler implementation.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, i accede.  i thought of adding the name of the technique.

Comment: @alvin, no objections on my part ;-)